# Opengraph - Linter does not fetch thumbnail with spaces (%20 or +) in address

Tags: php, image, url, urlencode, facebook-opengraph

I have setup my website so now I have opengraph meta tags which works correctly except when there is a space in the URL.

I use php and I was encoding urls with encodeurl (spaces are replaced by '+').
Then I try to encode the og:image address with rawencodeurl (spaces are replaced by '%20') and it still does not work.

You can see here http://dante.kollok.org/PhotoShow-dev/?f=noel%202011%20francais%20russe%20anglais%2Fimg_8570.jpg that the opengraph meta tags are correctly setup:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://dante.kollok.org/PhotoShow-dev/?f=noel%202011%20francais%20russe%20anglais%2Fimg_8570.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Franck's Photos"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="Franck's Photos: noel 2011 francais russe anglais/img_8570.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://dante.kollok.org/PhotoShow-dev/?t=Thb&f=noel%202011%20francais%20russe%20anglais%2Fimg_8570.jpg"/>
```

What clean solution do you suggest so facebook can properly fetch my thumbnail image even when I have spaces in the address?

Many thanks,
Franck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue with Facebook. See 
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/308448919183678

Your current workaround, and cleanest solution, is to put your image needed for facebook into a folder on the webserver that can be accessed without spaces or query string parameters.